# Getting Conditional Count in Join with Laravel Query Builder

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I am trying to achieve the following with Laravel Query builder.

I have a table called deals . Below is the basic schema

```
id
deal_id
merchant_id
status
deal_text
timestamps
```

I also have another table called merchants whose schema is

```
id
merchant_id
merchant_name
about
timestamps
```

Currently I am getting deals using the following query

```
$deals = DB::table('deals')
        -> join ('merchants', 'deals.merchant_id', '=', 'merchants.merchant_id')
        -> where ('merchant_url_text', $merchant_url_text)
        -> get();
```

Since only 1 merchant is associated with a deal, I am getting deals and related merchant info with the query.

Now I have a 3rd table called tbl_deal_votes. Its schema looks like

```
id
deal_id
vote (1 if voted up, 0 if voted down)
timestamps
```

What I want to do is join this 3rd table (on deal_id) to my existing query and be able to also get the upvotes and down votes each deal has received.

Comment: Just to start off with, why do you use `id` and `deal_id` in the `deals` table? Similarly for the merchant also?

Answer (score 1):

To do this in a single query you'll probably need to use SQL subqueries, which doesn't seem to have good fluent query support in Laravel 4/5. Since you're not using Eloquent objects, the raw SQL is probably easiest to read.  (Note the below example ignores your `deals.deal_id` and `merchants.merchant_id` columns, which can likely be dropped. Instead it just uses your `deals.id` and `merchants.id` fields by convention.)

```
$deals = DB::select(
    DB::raw('
        SELECT
            deals.id AS deal_id,
            deals.status,
            deals.deal_text,
            merchants.id AS merchant_id,
            merchants.merchant_name,
            merchants.about,
            COALESCE(tbl_upvotes.upvotes_count, 0) AS upvotes_count,
            COALESCE(tbl_downvotes.downvotes_count, 0) AS downvotes_count
        FROM
            deals
        JOIN merchants ON (merchants.id = deals.merchant_id)
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT deal_id, count(*) AS upvotes_count
            FROM tbl_deal_votes
            WHERE vote = 1 && deal_id
            GROUP BY deal_id
        ) tbl_upvotes ON (tbl_upvotes.deal_id = deals.id)
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT deal_id, count(*) AS downvotes_count
            FROM tbl_deal_votes
            WHERE vote = 0
            GROUP BY deal_id
        ) tbl_downvotes ON (tbl_downvotes.deal_id = deals.id)
    ')
);
```

If you'd prefer to use fluent, this should work:

```
$upvotes_subquery = '
    SELECT deal_id, count(*) AS upvotes_count
    FROM tbl_deal_votes
    WHERE vote = 1
    GROUP BY deal_id';

$downvotes_subquery = '
    SELECT deal_id, count(*) AS downvotes_count
    FROM tbl_deal_votes
    WHERE vote = 0
    GROUP BY deal_id';

$deals = DB::table('deals')
    ->select([
        DB::raw('deals.id AS deal_id'),
        'deals.status',
        'deals.deal_text',
        DB::raw('merchants.id AS merchant_id'),
        'merchants.merchant_name',
        'merchants.about',
        DB::raw('COALESCE(tbl_upvotes.upvotes_count, 0) AS upvotes_count'),
        DB::raw('COALESCE(tbl_downvotes.downvotes_count, 0) AS downvotes_count')
    ])
    ->join('merchants', 'merchants.id', '=', 'deals.merchant_id')
    ->leftJoin(DB::raw('(' . $upvotes_subquery . ') tbl_upvotes'), function($join) {
        $join->on('tbl_upvotes.deal_id', '=', 'deals.id');
    })
    ->leftJoin(DB::raw('(' . $downvotes_subquery . ') tbl_downvotes'), function($join) {
        $join->on('tbl_downvotes.deal_id', '=', 'deals.id');
    })
    ->get();
```

A few notes about the fluent query:

1. Used the DB::raw() method to rename a few selected columns.
   Otherwise, there would have been a conflict between `deals.id`
   and `merchants.id` in the results.
2. Used COALESCE to default `null` votes to 0.
3. Split the subqueries into separate PHP strings to improve readability.
4. Used left joins for the subqueries so deals with no upvotes/downvotes still show up.